# How can this kind of code be optimized?

Tags: optimization

Earlier today I saw one of my friends share a post on Google Reader (too long, at the end of this question).

Personally I think this piece of code is acceptable. But I am wondering what can be done to optimize this kind of code.

What I have come up with so far is to have a builder to get things done. However, it does not help much, especially when all the fields are mandatory.

Any insights?

EDIT:

By *optimize*, I mean, when other programmers see this piece of code ,they won't say WTF.

---

Code: Do not try to understand the names of the fields. They are initials of non-English.

```
public CktsQfxxHsh(String hjBh, String fqfZt, String jsfZt, String qcrDm,  
        String qcrXm, String fhrDm, String fhrXm, String qfrDm,  
        String qfrXm, String nsrsbhGf, String nsrxmGf, String nsrsbhXf,  
        String nsrxmXf, String swjgDmJsf, String swjgDmFqf,  
        String swjgJcFqf, String swjgJcJsf, String bfpryDm, String bspryMc,  
        String lxrXm, String lxrDh, String lxrDz, String lxrYb, Date sjSc,  
        Date sjFs, Date sjTjfh, Date sjTjqf, String hjLx, BigDecimal fpfs,  
        BigDecimal jeHj, BigDecimal seHj, BigDecimal jshjHj, String qtqk,  
        BigDecimal tseY, BigDecimal tseZbbl, String fhsm, Date fuhjzrq,  
        Date rqTk, Date sjFuhfs, String dyfhBh, String yqfhBz, String fhBz,  
        String cbBz, Date sjCbhfs) {  
    this.hjBh = hjBh;  
    this.fqfZt = fqfZt;  
    this.jsfZt = jsfZt;  
    this.qcrDm = qcrDm;  
    this.qcrXm = qcrXm;  
    this.fhrDm = fhrDm;  
    this.fhrXm = fhrXm;  
    this.qfrDm = qfrDm;  
    this.qfrXm = qfrXm;  
    this.nsrsbhGf = nsrsbhGf;  
    this.nsrxmGf = nsrxmGf;  
    this.nsrsbhXf = nsrsbhXf;  
    this.nsrxmXf = nsrxmXf;  
    this.swjgDmJsf = swjgDmJsf;  
    this.swjgDmFqf = swjgDmFqf;  
    this.swjgJcFqf = swjgJcFqf;  
    this.swjgJcJsf = swjgJcJsf;  
    this.bfpryDm = bfpryDm;  
    this.bspryMc = bspryMc;  
    this.lxrXm = lxrXm;  
    this.lxrDh = lxrDh;  
    this.lxrDz = lxrDz;  
    this.lxrYb = lxrYb;  
    this.sjSc = sjSc;  
    this.sjFs = sjFs;  
    this.sjTjfh = sjTjfh;  
    this.sjTjqf = sjTjqf;  
    this.hjLx = hjLx;  
    this.fpfs = fpfs;  
    this.jeHj = jeHj;  
    this.seHj = seHj;  
    this.jshjHj = jshjHj;  
    this.qtqk = qtqk;  
    this.tseY = tseY;  
    this.tseZbbl = tseZbbl;  
    this.fhsm = fhsm;  
    this.fuhjzrq = fuhjzrq;  
    this.sjFuhfs = sjFuhfs;  
    this.dyfhBh = dyfhBh;  
    this.yqfhBz = yqfhBz;  
    this.fhBz = fhBz;  
    this.cbBz = cbBz;  
    this.sjCbhfs = sjCbhfs;  
}
```

Comment: The first "optimization" seems like it would be to choose more appropriate variable/parameter names. This looks like an exercise in intentional obfuscation to me...

Comment: And more to the point, what do you mean by "optimized"? Do you want to make it run faster? Do you want to make it clearer? Do you want to make it require fewer lines of code?

Comment: @Cody Gray, yeah. Agree. But I have to say this might bring the pain of overwhelming typing.

Comment: "Code: Do not try to understand the names of the fields. They are initials of non-English." I hope the initials mean *something* to *someone*. I wonder what this implies for maintainability.

Comment: @pavium, as a native speaker, it can (to some extent) be inferred.

Comment: @dante-jiang what language using?

Comment: @php-coder, to be accurate, [Pinyin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin)

Comment: @dante-jiang I'm asking about programming language :) Java, PHP?

Comment: @php-coder, sorry.... maybe Java. I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregarding the variable names (as I think you are requesting) the only other problem is that there are too many of them. Does the caller of this constructor (I'm assuming Java) really have all those values sitting around as discrete variables, or do groups of them form sub-objects? It looks like there's a systematic structure to your variable names. The code might be improved by reflecting that structure in your object model rather than relying on naming conventions.

Comment: +1. one sign of bad design is having too many arguments. without more context, it is hard to say, but probably the string objects could be "grouped" into other data structures, or objects, redesigning the object methods, etc...

Comment: Yeah I'm not exactly sure what object you must be modelling to need a dozen strings or so. If it's some kind of property storage, a HashMap would work wonders (although a bit less efficient)

Comment: If I can think of a better word choice than "reflect" I'll edit my answer. I meant "reflect" in the sense of showing the characteristics of something.  Different or additional classes could provide more structure or organization to the data, which might lead to a better model of the corner of the world the program deals with.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the parameters generally come from objects that could group values together, or could sensibly be combined into objects that group values together, you could shorten the code by passing those objects instead of passing the individual values.  But I think this will only reduce coding if those other objects already exist or can be used more optimally elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you use Java language. In this case if `CktsQfxxHsh()` is constructor and arguments is a names of fields which marks as `final` then you may autogenerate constructor by using [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html):

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CktsQfxxHsh {
    final String hjBh;
    final String fqfZt;
    ...
}
```